# How to see PHP debugbar? (now showing up only when error 404)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, php-7

I have been trying since weeks now to debug my laravel/vuejs app with absolutely no success, so I am trying to understand what happens . I am debugging the "old way", displaying errors manually... And I get a bit crazy :)

PHP debugbar seems fabulous but for some reason it only shows up when I have a 404 error... I Would like to see it all the time.

[image]

Also, "dd()" juste doesnt do anything when I do for example:

```
public function emailexists(string $email){
        dd($email);

        //this doesn't work either
        var_dump($email);
        die();
}
```

I guess there is something I forgot. I am a beginner with PHP.

EDIT: could it be because I am using VueJS ?

EDIT2: after Thomas' answer :
I guess the lifecycle is ended correctly (unless I need to do something specific? I am just calling my PHP controller through axios from my vueJS view)

But here is my view.blade, could it be the issue?

```
@extends('template')
@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <vuecomponent ></vuecomponent >
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

The debugbar [gets added at the end of the request lifecycle (after middleware)](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/master/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php#L55). Failing to properly end the lifecycle the intended way will yield the result of not having a debugbar. Both `dd` and `die` are PHP functions that stop execution immediately.

**As for VueJS:**

Vue itself will not show the debugbar, just because Laravel is installed next to the Vue entrypoint.
That doesn't have to be a problem if you use a (Blade) view to setup Vue. However if you bypass Laravel entirely on DOM output, that yes the debugbar won't be part of it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess the lifecycle is ended correctly (unless I need to do something specific; I am just calling my PHP controller through axios from my vueJS view)

But here is my view.blade, could it be the issue?

@extends('template')
@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <vuecomponent ></vuecomponent >
    </div>
@endsection

Comment: You need to "boot" vue also from laravel, as in your first get request / initial load of Vue should come from laravel as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you use PHP, Laravel or Vuejs all dd() or var_dump() would be useful if you can track your requests. May you just need to use a browser inspector which could show you requests responses.

Comment: This is what I would like to do: tracking my requests. Some of them are complex and  I waste a lot of time trying to understand why it fails. As DD doesn't work, it makes it difficult

Comment: DD works in all places in Laravel. :)) Except, your request get an error before reaching it. If your request IS AJAX req so you need to press F12 in your browser and track it in the network tab of your inspector.